# MSBuild in TeamCity for web applications don't copy referenced libraries

Tags: dll, reference, msbuild, copy, teamcity

I'm trying to use msbuild in TeamCity to configure buildserver for preparing builds. Everything seems to be ok, except that msbuild doesn't copy referenced libraries via project referece, e.g. I have a project that uses `SSH.NET`, and my Web App uses that project, but I can't force msbuild to copy that `SSH.NET` library to Web App publish folder.

I use this msbuild xml:

```
    <MSBuild Projects="$(WebAppDir)\WebApp.csproj"
         Targets="ResolveReferences; _WPPCopyWebApplication"
         Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration); Platform=$(Platform); WebProjectOutputDir=..\$(ReleaseOutputDir)\$(WebAppDir)\"
             />
```

I've also tried to use `SLN` builder. Using this builder Teamcity copies all libraries, but it's not a publish build.

What I've tried to do? Checking other threads on SO, I've tried:

1. Add tag `<private>True...` to csproj file of dependent project;
2. Changing properties of referenced library to all possible values: copy local to true, false, content etc;
3. I've also tried to use `nuget installer` step in order to resolve references.

   But neither of this worked for me.

   Mb there is another way for getting publish builds of web apps in msbuild? Or how do I supposed to make msbuild prepare builds identical to Visual Studio manual publish command builds?

Comment: Have you tried using the in built publish profiles instead? Uses MSBuild under the hood, but a lot easier to set up. Check out this great article by Troy Hunt. Helped me a lot http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/11/you-deploying-it-wrong-teamcity.html

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I would mention I recently spent 2 days trying to figure out why TeamCity wasn't copying referenced assemblies. And it turns out that it was because although the assembly was "Referenced" under "References" and Copy Local to true, it wasn't copying it because the assembly was being loaded dynamically at runtime. What i had to do, is add a single line, to create any object from that library, which TeamCity then managed to pick up and copy the referenced assembly. I dont know if this will help in your scenario.